# How to change value in one of the attributes?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an this source xml document:

```
<A>
  <B VALUE = "1"/>
  <B VALUE = "1"/>
</A>
```

What XSLT transformation to use to transform the above XML document to this:

```
<A>
  <B VALUE = "1"/>
  <B VALUE = "2"/>
</A>
```

Comment: What is the logic that needs to be applied here? IOW, what makes the attribute you want to change special? And where does the new value of `2` come from?

Comment: It's too long to explain the logic... but shortly I just need to have double attribute with two different values "1" & "2" are just examples... Could you help with that? Or maybe you know other solution to this problem?

Comment: I cannot help you with a problem I do not understand. You need to select one of the attributes. You could select the 2nd one. Or the last one. Or the first one that is a duplicate. Or any other possibility out of an endless number.

Comment: Select an attribute... THANK YOU! :D

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that in the wanted output the value of the `VALUE` attribute should be the position of its parent element in the sequence `/A/B`

**Then this transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="B/@VALUE[not(. = count(../preceding-sibling::B) +1 )]">
    <xsl:attribute name="VALUE">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::B) + 1"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<A>
  <B VALUE = "1"/>
  <B VALUE = "1"/>
</A>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<A>
   <B VALUE="1"/>
   <B VALUE="2"/>
</A>
```